# Use an unreleased dependency in SBT

Tags: playframework, sbt, slick, typesafe

I would like to use an unreleased version of Slick from GitHub.

I have:

```
settings = Project.defaultSettings ++ Seq(
  scalaVersion := "2.11.6",
  libraryDependencies ++= List(
    "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "3.1.1",
    "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick-codegen" % "3.1.1",
    "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-nop" % "1.7.12",
    "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.37"
  ),
  slick <<= slickCodeGenTask, // register manual sbt command
  sourceGenerators in Compile <+= slickCodeGenTask // register automatic code generation on every compile, remove for only manual use
)
```

Is it possible to remove 3.1.1 and get the latest version from github? I need this because of a merge that fixed an critical issue for my project.

Is it better to download Slick from GitHub, build it and use the generated jar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on whether the jars (with that fix included) have been published to a location you can point your sbt to. If they haven't you're better off grabbing the source (with fix) yourself, compiling and running `publish-local`. I had a quick look on [bintray.com](http://bintray.com) but it's not clear from that site if they have published the jars.